# HTML/PHP/JS/MYSQL -- How to pass fairly big DIV content through form to MySQL?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, forms

**Hey guys!**

I'm currently playing with some kind of bracket, the page looks like this:
[image: Bracket]

The purpose is for the user to be able to pick winners in each pair simulating whole playoffs. Once he had made the simulation a form appears on the bottom:
[image]

What i can't manage to get working tho is for the form to pass not only `Imie`/`Email` fields (which is fairly easy), but also the whole bracket so that I can check brackets sent and compare.

I've heard that `ajax` would be of much help in this case so I wrote this script based on some info i found online (i'm new to ajax):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

            $('form').submit(function(event) {

                            var data = {
                                'name'              : $('input[name=name]').val(),
                                'email'             : $('input[name=email]').val(),
                                'formularz'         : $('#formdiv').val()
                            };

                            $.ajax({
                                type        : 'POST',
                                url         : 'process.php',
                                data        : data,
                                dataType    : 'json',
                                encode          : true
                            })
                                .done(function(data) {

                                    console.log(data); 

                                });

                            event.preventDefault();
                        });

                    });
```

`Process.php` looks as follows:

```
<?php

$errors         = array();
$data           = array();

    if (empty($_POST['name']))
        $errors['name'] = 'Imie jest wymagane.';

    if (empty($_POST['email']))
        $errors['email'] = 'Email jest wymagany.';

    if (empty($_POST['formularz']))
        $errors['formularz'] = 'Uzupełnij formularz.';

    if ( ! empty($errors)) {

        $data['success'] = false;
        $data['errors']  = $errors;
    } else {

        var imie = data.name;
        alert(imie);

        $data['success'] = true;
        $data['message'] = 'Success!';
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
```

From the ajax code, i assume i should get console.log with the form data, there are no logs though. Is it possible that form data is just too huge because of the big div stored and fails because of it?

Would be grateful for any help!

Here is the link for the full code and HTML:

- https://codeshare.io/5R7pzE

sample of the html code:

```
<div id="formdiv">
    <div class="col-cell">
        <div class="row" id="team1">
            <?php
                $team1 = "SELECT id, timestamp, teamname, teamtag FROM teams WHERE id = '1'";

                $result = mysqli_query($con, $team1);
                if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
                        echo '<div class="team-block">';
                        echo '<img src="img/basketball.png"/>';
                        echo '<div class="team-tag">';
                        echo "<h2>---</h2>";
                        echo '</div></div>';
                }
                else
                {;
                    while(list($id, $timestamp, $teamname, $teamtag) = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
                    {
                        $idfromsql = "SELECT * FROM teams WHERE id = $id";
                        $sthi = $con->query($idfromsql);
                        $imgresult = mysqli_fetch_array($sthi);

                        echo '<div class="team-block">';
                        echo '<div id="team111"><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $imgresult['data'] ).'"/></div>';
                        echo '<div class="team-tag">';
                        echo "<h2>$teamtag</h2>";
                        echo '</div></div>';

                    }

                };
                ?>
            <div class="numleft">1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="team2">
            <?php
                $team2 = "SELECT id, timestamp, teamname, teamtag FROM teams WHERE id = '2'";

                $result = mysqli_query($con, $team2);
                if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
                        echo '<div class="team-block">';
                        echo '<img src="img/basketball.png"/>';
                        echo '<div class="team-tag">';
                        echo "<h2>---</h2>";
                        echo '</div></div>';
                }
                else
                {;
                    while(list($id, $timestamp, $teamname, $teamtag) = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
                    {
                        $idfromsql = "SELECT * FROM teams WHERE id = $id";
                        $sthi = $con->query($idfromsql);
                        $imgresult = mysqli_fetch_array($sthi);

                        echo '<div class="team-block" onclick="adv1();">';
                        echo '<div id="team211"><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $imgresult['data'] ).'"/></div>';


                        echo '<div class="team-tag">';
                        echo "<h2>$teamtag</h2>";
                        echo '</div></div>';

                    }

                };
                ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add `success: function(data) { console.log(data)}` to your ajax function. That should log out the data that gets echoed out from the php.

Comment: I am guessing `#formdiv` is div so  `$('#formdiv').val()` will return nothing. to be honest i dont know what you are trying to do. you can use .val() on inputs and textarea

Comment: The OP is already sending the data to `console.log()` @DiddleDot - look in the `.done()` function.

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: you may also have to post the HTML for this. Plus, you should use proper bracing for every condition; it's best.

Comment: I will only answer this part *How to pass fairly big DIV content through form to MySQL?*  `$('#divId').text();` will give u the content inside that div then u do what ever u wanna do with that content

Comment: https://codeshare.io/5R7pzE  here's the HTML code of #formdiv

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile i'll give it a try in a moment

Comment: @DamianDoman --- Masivuye may not be in the question. Use the @ as I did for you here and for any others you wish to address directly. You have time to edit if you wish.

Comment: @DamianDoman let us know how did tht go? did u implement as per the answer below?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile yeah, seems like it still won't get content of `formdiv`, even though I've used both `text()` and `html()`. i can guess the data it gets from address bar query string (`?name=5g&email=34f34`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var data = {
   'name'              : $('input[name=name]').val(),
   'email'             : $('input[name=email]').val(),
   'formularz'         : $('#formdiv').val()
};
```

formularz is empty, because the .val() function is only working on input-fields.
If you really want to transfer the complete div, use .html(), or .text().

Easier way, use hidden inputs based on the solutions made.

Comment: i've also been thinking on hidden inputs, but it seems like a cheap workaround for me haha, i'll give text/html a try in a moment, thanks for contributing!

Comment: address bar query string outputs `?name=5g&email=34f34` so I guess `#formdiv` still is not being stored, maybe it's just too big? (probably few hundreds characters in there)

Comment: I wouldn't say it is a hack to use hidden input fields. Especially on communicating to php

Comment: well, it definitely would offer much more elasticity. So let me make my mind up - i could for example put an radio input for every pair, add onClick jquery handlers to tick the chosen teams radio, and pass for example `teamid` as value right?